# Is it possible to access value being evaluated with ternary conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if its possible to access the value being considered when using the ternary conditional operator.

e.g.:

```
const dict = new Map<Foo, Bar>();

const x = dict.get("foo") !== undefined ? dict.get("foo") : new Bar();
```

Is there any way to get rid of the repeated `dict.get("foo")` in this ternary expression?

Comment: Are you specifically married to `!== undefined`? Then no: there's no elegant shorthand for that. Otherwise, if simply a *truthy* test would do too, there's a common idiom for that…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `?:` operator is evaluating *expressions*. You're giving it the expression `dict.get("foo") !== undefined`, which is a boolean expression. There's no way for the `?:` operator to isolate just the `dict.get("foo")` within that expression to refer to later.

If you need the specific `!== undefined` test, then no, there's no other way. To avoid the repetitive method call you could only refactor that to:

```
let x = dict.get("foo");
if (x === undefined) {
    x = new Bar();
}
```

However, if a *truthy* comparison will do instead of specifically the test for `undefined`, this is the common idiom:

```
const x = dict.get("foo") || new Bar();
```

Comment: `const x = dict.get("foo") ?? new Bar();` is more closer to a `undefined` check. I say closer because it also will evaluate `false` for a `null`. The `||` check you have posted is testing for all truthy (null, 0, false... etc)